# Outlook Conversation History

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am looking into creating an outlook plugin that I can select a conversation from the Conversation History folder and then click a button that saves it to a folder.  Does anyone have any pointers to how I can select the Conversation History Folder and Run Searches via C# as well as selecting conversations.

Comment: Also when using my methods below be sure to use the Global.OutlookApplication or whatever you are calling the Addin.

From that it returns a List of Mail Objects so just format it to whatever datasource you want each field of it to be displayed.

Comment: May as well put this comment into the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static List<Outlook.MAPIFolder> GetFolders()
    {

        List<Outlook.MAPIFolder> _list = new List<Outlook.MAPIFolder>();

        Outlook.MAPIFolder root = OutlookApplication.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder();


        foreach (Outlook.MAPIFolder folder in root.Folders)
        {
            _list.Add(folder);
        }

        return _list;
    }

    public static Outlook.MAPIFolder GetFolderByEntryId(string entryId)
    {
        List<Outlook.MAPIFolder> folders = GetFolders();
        return folders.Where(x => x.EntryID == entryId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static Outlook.MAPIFolder GetFolderByName(string folderName)
    {
        List<Outlook.MAPIFolder> folders = GetFolders();
        return folders.Where(x => x.Name == folderName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And

```
    public static List<Outlook.MailItem> GetSelectedItem()
    {
        List<Outlook.MailItem> _list = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();

        Outlook.Selection outlookSelection = OutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

        for (int i = 1; i < outlookSelection.Count; i++)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookSelection[i];

            _list.Add(mailItem);
        }

        return _list;
    }

    public static List<Outlook.MailItem> GetMailItems(string FolderName)
    {
        List<Outlook.MailItem> _list = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();

        Outlook.MAPIFolder theFolder = OutlookApplication.Session.GetFolderFromID(GetFolderByName(FolderName).EntryID);

        foreach (Object item in theFolder.Items)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)item;

            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                _list.Add(mailItem);
            }
        }

        return _list;

    }
```

Comment: Posting the solution encase anyone needs it.  As the Microsoft Document library gives a very roundabout way of doing things.